# how can i fix this error that nodemon keep on showing

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

i following an express.js tutorial andd after some code and functionalities with api requests i followed exactly how he changed the code that handles these requests into a seperate js file in another folder just to clean up the code but after i did that this error showed up

i tried changing the file name , i tried removing the node-modules folder and running npm install again and i tried installing the module with the issue

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module '/routes/api/members'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Get_Rico\Desktop\crashcoursse\index.js:11:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

i expect nodemon to save the changes and work just fine with no errors just like what happened in the tutorial

Comment: I think your path just needs a . at the beginning './routes/api/members' assuming that the rest of the path is really where you have the members.js file.

Comment: bro it worked :o :o :o all i was missing was a '.' thank you

Comment: it is a path issue. can you share your directory structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the error is probably coming from this line of code and it's telling you that it can't find the '/routes/api/members' module file.

And, this would not be working because you're trying to load a local module without a proper path name. If no path is specified, then it tries to load a global or built-in module. If that module is in the current directory, then you should use the correct path:

```
const yourModule = './routes/api/members';
```